# Running Scala function from command line

Tags: java, scala, command-line, read-eval-print-loop, scalac

I'm working on an exercise. I need to create a java project that can be run from the scala command line. The final output should be this:

```
scala> int2str(6)
res0: String = six

scala> int2str(65)
res0: String = sixty-five
```

How do I create a function that can be accessed by scala like that? I can create a Scala project in IntelliJ, but I don't know how to export that function to be used like that.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you define the function just in Scala console?

Comment: You don't need to "export" anything. You want the REPL to import or load the function. How to do that depends somewhat on what form the function is in. Is it compiled in a `.jar` file? In any event, try `scala -help` on your shell command line and read about the various options.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following scala code:

```scala
object A {
 def int2str(i: Int): String = ""
}
```

You can just make a jar file from your scala project with a command
`sbt package` for instance, then run `scala -cp <your jar>`.
In the scala console just import your function:

```scala
import A.int2str
```